# Куда android studio по умолчанию сохраняет файлы?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, файлы

В коде программы записываю строку в файл

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("list.txt", false)){
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String string = editText.getText().toString();
            file.write(string);
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Однако потом никак в папке с проектом не могу найти этот файл. Куда студия его сохраняет по умолчанию?

Comment: `IOException` у вас будет и ничего никуда не запишется. Нельзя в Андроид просто взять и писть куда захочется. Вот здесь все об этом: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Answer (score 2):

Вы пишете приложение под ОС андроид и запускаете его на девайсе/эмуляторе, не на машине, на которой компилируете и собираете.

А андроид приложение пишет файлы на тот девайс, на котором запущено. Таким образом вам надо искать файл не в проекте, но в файловой системе телефона. Скорее всего прямо в корне его диска.

Comment: перерыл все папки и .android и .AndroidStudio3.1, но все равно нигде не нашел. Запускаю через эмулятор. Где он вообще хранится? Мне казалось, что он в папке со студией должен

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii, сказано же - в файловой системе эмулятора, а не компьютера. Но скорее всего он вообще не пишется и если заглянете в LogCat узнаете почему.

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii, ищите через эмулятор, не на компе. Хз где и в каком формате комп хранит файлы эмулятора. И да, скорее всего у вас файл не записался, т.к. выкидывает ошибку отсутствия разрешения пользователя на запись, если вы на ОС>6 версии запускаете.

Comment: ФС запущенного эмулятора/подключенного устройства можно увидеть в Device File Explorer (`Menu->View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer`)